# regex c# cSharp - checking string only Alphabet and one space " " and one "-"

Tags: c#

sorry for my english ^^

I am trying to control the input of the user. the validation must accept only a single "" space a single "-" and only alphabet letter.

exemple "-" : `Jean-MArc` is accept
`Jean--Marc` not accept

exemple " " : `el meyda` is accept

user can delete to correct

I am a beginner in c #

my code :

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        Console.WriteLine("enter your Name");
        string enterUser = Console.ReadLine();

        string pattern = "^\w*[- ]?\w*$";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(enterUser, pattern)) Console.WriteLine("no match");
        
        else Console.WriteLine(" match");
```

Comment: Can you give us  an example of the exact string you want matched, e.g. `" -"`, and an example of what you've tried? The javascript you've found might also be helpful.

Comment: Probably `^([^ ]* [^ ]*|[^-]*-[^-]*)$`

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov matches ```.        -       .``` :-)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Agree

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you need

```
^\w*[- ]?\w*$

"a"    - match
"ab"   - match
" ab"  - match
"ab "  - match
"a b"  - match
"a-b"  - match
"a b " - no match
"a-b " - no match
"a- b" - no match
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, when you say 'only alphabet letter' you mean no numbers or special characters and you want to support non-ascii letters.

(Using `\w` means numbers are included)

C# Regex has a class for all unicode characters defined as 'letters': `\p{L}`

So you might try this:

```
@"^\p{L}*[- ]?\p{L}*$"
```

It will match letters only with max one hyphen (`-`) or space.

Comment: I LOVE YOU !!! thx my friends

Comment: to better understand the logic of adding two spaces instead of one?

Comment: The question mark (`?`) means: zero or one of the characters in square brackets.